# Taking input as an integer separated by spaces in python

Tags: python, list, integer

So I have gotten the program to work, my problem so far is that my solution requires that the output look like this `[44, 76, 34, 98, 1, 99]` but I keep getting `['1', '2', '3', '5', '6', '7']` if my input was `44 76 44 34 98 34 1 44 99 1 1 1`

Trying to convert the final solution into an int and then back into a string does not work, I still end up with quotations.

The point of the code BTW is to remove duplicates from a given input and print it out in a list

```
def eliminateDuplicates(lst): 
    newlist = []
    for number in lst:
        if number not in newlist:
            newlist.append(number)
    return newlist

def main():
    numbers =(input("Enter numbers separated by space: "))
    x = ((numbers.split()))
    print("The distinct numbers are: ", (eliminateDuplicates(x))) 

main()
```

Comment: Are you asking _why_ the quotes are there or how to get rid of them?  The answer to the first question should be pretty easy, right?  `input` gives you a string and `split` breaks up a string into a **list of strings**.  Perhaps you can take it from here?  List comprehensions?  `map`?  Lots of choices for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taking in integer input separated by space (invalid literal error) Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720180/taking-in-integer-input-separated-by-space-invalid-literal-error-python)

Answer (score 1):

In the first line we store the input in d.
In the second line we convert d into set() and back to list().
In the third line we map() d to integer.

```
d = raw_input("Enter Numbers: ").split()
d = list(set(d))
d = map(int, d)
print d
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print("The distinct numbers are: ", map(int, eliminateDuplicates(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using map helped get me my solution. BTW can you please explain how map works if you don't mind. The functions page does not really do a good job at explaining it.

Comment: Sure. `map(a, lst)` means "take this function of one argument, `a`, apply it to each member of list `lst`, and return a list of the results." So, for example, `map(lambda x: x+1, [1,2,3])` would return `[2,3,4]`.

Comment: `map`, along with (whatever your language calls 'em) `reduce` and `filter`, are the basic building blocks of [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). If you ever learn a LISP-like language, Clojure, Scala, Erlang, Haskell, or a similar language, you'll get comfortable with it. Happy coding!

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thank you so much Christian, you would make a better teacher than a lot of mine, lol.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter `lst` is supposed to be a `list`, why don't you enter a list as input? (Instead of numbers separated by space). Then you can ommit the `split` stuff:

```
def eliminateDuplicates(lst): 
    newlist = []
    for number in lst:
        if number not in newlist:
            newlist.append(number)
    return newlist

def main():
    numbers =(input("Enter numbers as a list: "))
    print("The distinct numbers are: ", (eliminateDuplicates(numbers))) 
main()
```

Comment: I was told that the input has to be a integer. and yeah just using the map function got me my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your problem says specifically: the input must be an integer. Then you may want to read them one by one. Because when you are giving the input by separated spaces, that's a `string`. (Just taking it literally)

Comment: This answer only works in Python 2. In Python 3 (which I suspect the questioner is using), `input` is equivalent to Python 2's `raw_input`. So `input()` always returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def eliminateDuplicates(lst): 
    newlist = [int(x) for x in lst]
    newlist = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(newlist))
    return newlist

def main():
    numbers =(input("Enter numbers separated by space: "))
    x = ((numbers.split()))
    print("The distinct numbers are: ", (eliminateDuplicates(x))) 
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting quotation marks around your numbers when you print them is because you're printing a `list`, which implicitly converts the list to a string (using `str`). The `list` type's `__str__` method uses the `repr` of each of its list items. The `repr` of a string puts quotes around it.

There's a good reason for this. `repr` is supposed to be a computer-friendly represnetation of an object. If possible, it should create a duplicate of the object when `eval`ed. If lists or strings behaved differently when printed, a list like `["foo", "bar, baz", "quux"]` would have an ambiguous `repr`.

Converting the input values to integers (as other answers have suggested) is one solution, but not a necessary one for this task. Your deduplicating function works just fine with lists of strings. If the output formatting is the only issue, you can `str.format` and `str.join` to create an output string in the form you want from your list of strings, rather than printing the list directly. For instance:

```
print("The distinct numbers are: [{}]".format(", ".join(eliminateDuplicates(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line of your code.

```
x =[ int(num) for num in numbers.split(' ') if len(num)>0 ]
```

Everything will work fine.
After changing this line, your whole code will look like below

```
def eliminateDuplicates(lst): 
newlist = []
for number in lst:
    if number not in newlist:
        newlist.append(number)
return newlist

def main():
    numbers =(input("Enter numbers separated by space: "))
    x =[ int(num) for num in numbers.split(' ') if len(num)>0 ]
    print("The distinct numbers are: ", (eliminateDuplicates(x))) 

main()
```

Output will be

```
Enter numbers separated by space: 44 76 44 34 98 34 1 44 99 1 1 1
The distinct numbers are:  [44, 76, 34, 98, 1, 99]
```

At the time of reading space separated inputs in python , they are treated as string so you need to convert them into integer. strings can be converted into integers in many ways like below 
**Using list comprehension**

```
numbers = [ int(num) for num in input().split(' ') if len(num)>0 ]
```

**Using filter and map function**

```
numbers = list(map(int,filter(lambda x : len(x)>0,input().split(' '))))
```